# What are some standard methods for studying co-ocurrence patterns?

Tags: clustering, categorical-data

We have a series of academic articles annotated with several tags eg "environmental issues", "legal issues", etc.

I wish to understand whether some of these topics are frequently discussed together.

What are some standard clustering methods we could apply?

So far what we have tried is plotting a heatmap of the co-ocurrence matrix.

[image]